# OS X Customise Title Bar Colour

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, titlebar

I was wondering if there is any way to customise the default silver gradient that is used by most OS X apps as the window title bar background colour. I am using OS X 10.9. I have found solutions such as the "Flavours" app, however I was wondering if there was a way of doing it manually so that I don't have to purchase softwares to achieve the desired effect. I do not wish for a programmatical answer (I.e. For if I was programming an application), but instead am wondering if it is possible to change the system default.

Thanks- Slendy

Comment: The appropriate place for this question is `http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct solution but you might want to dig through all the PNGs in `/System`. It is not recommended to change the files in there though. Tools changing the appearance of OS X are using extensions and do not alter your system installation. So always have a backup!

To get a list of say all PNGs open your Terminal.app and type in:

```
find /System -name *.png
```

You can also open up the Activity Monitor and inspect "Open files" in a process' information panel. This way I found that `/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/toolbar-leather.png` is the image used in the Notes.app and I was able to alter it:

[image: altered OS X window title]

Disclaimer: I'm not a designer :)